# Can fopen fail if the file already exists (in write mode)?

Tags: c, file

I wish to open a new file using `fopen("/temp/abc.txt", "w")`

I want that if the file already exists, `fopen` should fail so that I can retry by changing the name. Ex - rename to `abc_1.txt`.

`access()` is not my preferred way because there is a possibility that a file gets created after `access()` call check and before `fopen()`.

What is the better way to handle this?

Comment: Maybe `"wx"` create text file for writing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C11, [`fopen` supports a new mode modifier `"x"`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html) that does what you require.  I'm not aware of any portable ways to do this in earlier standards, however.

Most operating systems do support such a flag in their platform-specific file-opening primitives.  On POSIX systems this can be achieved with `O_EXCL`, while on Windows this can be achieved with `CREATE_ALWAYS`.

Answer (score 3):

On a POSIX system, you could use the [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) function or one of its relatives to create the file, returning a file descriptor, and then use [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) to create a file stream from the file descriptor.  Amongst other advantages, this allows you to control the permissions on the file that is created more accurately than the standard I/O library will ever allow.

```
int fd = open(target_file, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0600);
if (fd < 0)
    …report error and return or exit…
FILE *fp = fdopen(fd, "w+");
if (fp == 0)
    …report error and return or exit…

…use file stream fp…

fclose(fp);
// Do not close(fd) too, and especially not before the fclose(fp)!
```

Answer (score 0):

As a random thought, if you don't want to/can't use the "x" flag (which is probably the best way), you could try using "a" instead of "w", and then checking `tell() == 0`. This will accept both non-existent and empty files, however.